# creating asp application with rich text and dynamic row controls

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, excel

I am familiar with `C#` standalones but never written any web applications. I need some pointers on `c# asp.net` applications to do following stuffs.

Create a table profile, insert rows and columns with rich text edit controls,  ability to insert images(low priority) and dynamic row manipulations like move rows, insert custom rows (e.g. a data row from a db that can be inserted into my current table profile) and then export different table profiles into tabbed `excel sheet`.

I am looking at:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850837%28office.14%29.aspx
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/hrojasara/export-datagridview-to-excel-in-C-Sharp/
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/820176/ASP-NET-Gridview-with-Row-Drag-and-Drop-using-Jque
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/467788/Dynamically-adding-and-deleting-rows-from-ASP-NET

I will do my research but since i have no experience on controls available if someone points in right directions on concepts  which is suitable for this as this looks more complex for 1st app it will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you **Kendo UI framework** that allows to do what you need. This is a website with demo - **http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index**. It allows to make Excel and PDF export as well.

Comment: Thanks upvoted.. Looks promising but cant really afford it. But looks like jQuery options are the way to go.